# ADF - startTime & endTime dynamic content - 1st and last day of the month

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

I'm trying to add dynamic content to the relative URL of a REST connection in Azure Data factory that is making an API call to the azure consumption API. I want to automate the fetching of data from the current billing period which is defined by the 1st and last day of the current month.

I've tried adding the following dynamic content, but it is returning dates that are further away. I want to have it return the 1st and last day of the current month. I know this is not simple as there are not the same amount of days in each month.

```
@concat('?startTime=', adddays(utcnow(),-31,'yyyy-MM-dd'),'&endTime=', 
adddays(utcnow(),+31,'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Expected result: return 1st day of the month in startTime and last day of the month in endTime.

Actual results:

```
{
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorHttpStatusCodeIndicatingFailure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The HttpStatusCode 400 indicates failure.  {\"error\":{\"code\":\"400\"&#44;\"message\":\"Parameter: endTime. Value is greater than 2019-06-01\"}},Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Copy Data2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first day: `adddays(utcnow(), 0,'yyyy-MM-'), '01'`

expression:
`@concat('?startTime=', adddays(utcnow(), 0,'yyyy-MM-'), '01','&endTime=', 
adddays(utcnow(), 0,'yyyy-MM-dd'))`

Comment: Nice, this works! As long as I increment my dataset every day I will have the latest updates for the current month. Thanks Atvoid.